# Opencv Python: How to detect rectangular shapes on picture

Tags: python, opencv, game-automation

I have some photos like these:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I want to detect the white rectangular area in the above images with python opencv. Look same:

[image: Expect]

Please help me.
Thanks.

There are many different photos but the rectangular part is almost the same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).